# Correct way to store very large integers with maximum performance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am working on a game in which I would like to store very large numbers, in the trillions and quadrillions (a progression type game, a la Clicker Heroes, just doing it for fun).

Anyway, c# appears to have a 32-bit limit on integers, however, I can get floats to be very very large (eg. 999999999999999.0f)

However, is this the fastest way to store very large numbers in C#?

I do not need accuracy, so floating point-type solutions are fine. I just need speed and the ability to store very large integers.

Is a BigInt library the way to go? How do you recommend going about this?

Comment: Instead of going with what 'appears' to be, check what [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs7y5x0x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) says about it. It's always a good reflex to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Anyway, c# appears to have a 32-bit limit on integers, however, I can get floats to be very very large (eg. 999999999999999.0f)

This is categorically false. C# has the `long` and `ulong` types which correspond to .NET's `Int64` and `UInt64` types, which are both 64-bit integers which represent the number-ranges:

```
Int64 : -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to  9,223,372,036,854,775,807
UInt64:                          0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.
```

That's:

> Eighteen **quintillion**, four hundred and forty six quadrillion, seven hundred and forty four trillion, seventy-three billion, seven hundred and nine million, five hundred and fifty-one thousand, and six hundred and fifteen.

And if you need to store even bigger numbers you can always implement your own `UInt128` by joining two `UInt64` values together and using schoolbook techniques to combine the two for common arithmetic operations.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Sorry, I did it wrong. I'm redoing it now.

Comment: thank you, I'm new to C# (and strictly typed languages in general). was unaware of multiple int types.

Comment: There's already a `BigInteger` struct if you need arbitrarily large integer values.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen many games use doubles for this purpose.